# Setting restrictions on a user's password - is it appropriate?

Tags: passwords

Theoretical question here:

How do people feel about the restrictions that registration forms have for users' passwords? Meaning, is it wise to make a condition that the user must have a capital letter, a number and a special character? I recognize that those conditions usually would require users to make a more secure password, but would that be annoying to a majority of users (it annoys me that a website assumes I do not have the capacity to create a secure password)? Any opinions one way or the other?

Comment: Not really a programming question. Might be better on [IT Security](http://security.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Leigh, please see [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/140491/167534).

Comment: my bad if i posted this on the wrong site. I do fall into the category of the new users. Please merge this question or do anything that is appropriate.

Comment: I personally do not think there should be *any* restrictions, except a lower-length and some maximum sane upper limit (e.g. 60 charactes) and perhaps a character set (e.g. is Unicode supported through-and-through?) .. search google for "horse battery staple correct". Now, showing a "strength" indicator could encourage people to choose "more complex"/longer passwords ..

Comment: Might be worth having a scan through: http://ux.stackexchange.com/search?q=password - if you don't see a satisfactory answer then ask a new question there. Cheers.

Comment: @bfavaretto: I'm not trying to encourage cross-posting, I'm suggesting the OP might get a better informed answer if this question was migrated there.

Comment: @Leigh That's exactly the point of the post I linked to: this kind of comment may lead to confusion, and, sometimes, cross-posting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, pretty much. You should also make a JS script to check for the password strength while user is typing it in. Just to inform the user and not let him submit it before a certain strength level is reached.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend some sort of password requirement to ensure basic security. However, making the requirements too stringent will hurt usability and, if they're encountering a rule they're not familiar with, could force them to create a new password which they could later forget. My advice would be to look over the requirements for popular websites such as Google, Facebook, etc. to get an idea of common requirements. If they've already encountered whatever requirements your website uses, they're less likely to get upset and can reuse memorized passwords.

Note: I know password reuse is a bad idea, but the majority of internet users don't want to memorize a new password for each site they create an account for, and it's therefore best from a usability perspective to allow them to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You should also be careful about what characters you are going to allow in the password. Some secure input controls only allow ascii.